# Ember distinguish record which is requested from server with params and without params

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to get two records from the server without knowing the ID's. The first record is requested without params and the second record with params.

It looks something like this:

```
model: function(){

  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    cars: this.store.find('cars').then(function(car){
      return car.get('firstObject');
    }),

    carsWithRange: this.store.find('cars', {date_from: momentLast30Days}).then(function(car){
      return car.get('firstObject');
    })
  });
}
```

At the moment 'cars' and 'carsWithRange' sometimes returns the same record. I think this is happening because I use car.get('firstObject') from the cars models. Somehow I need to know that 'carsWithRange' is requested with the param 'date_from'.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

FYI I use Ember 1.12.1 with Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.15

Comment: Sounds like something you should be dealing with from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

We finally solved it in the frontend by using `this.store.findQuery` (with a query which doesn't make a lot of sense) instead of `this.store.find`. This returns the exact record which is given by the server. But yeah it feels a bit hacky.